# Sort a List of numeric Tuples with nested For Loops. .Net 4.0 C#

Tags: c#, sorting, for-loop, tuples, numeric

I have a List of numeric tuples  and want to sort it by Item1 with nested For Loops. I know I can just do List.Sort(); but I want to do it with For loops too so that I can compare the performance. I appreciate any help.

```
        List<Tuple<double, int, int>> FHM = new List<Tuple<double, int, int>>(); 
        FHM.Add(Tuple.Create(2500.00, 1, 5));
        FHM.Add(Tuple.Create(2400.00, 2, 300));    
        FHM.Add(Tuple.Create(2300.00, 4, 10));
        FHM.Add(Tuple.Create(2600.00, 1, 325));
```

I tried to implement the below code working fine sorting a list of doubles with nested for loops, but I can not recode it for tuples...

```
List<double> FH = new List<double>() { 2510, 2509, 2501.5, 2501.75 };


        var S1 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        double temp;
        for (int i = 0; i < FH.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int n = 0; n < i; n++)
            {
                if (FH[n] > FH[i])
                {
                    temp = FH[i];
                    FH[i] = FH[n];
                    FH[n] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        S1.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine($"S1 Ticks = " + S1.ElapsedTicks);
```

/* ElapsedTicks with the ForLoop are 4000. Whereas with FH.Sort(); are 16000. So I expect the ForLoop version with Tuples will perform better for the short lists I am working on. */

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you having problems? If you are just wanting to implement the sort yourself you can find plenty of sorting algorithms online and then just implement them. If you have trouble implementing it you can then come back with a more specific question.

Comment: You're using a very inefficient sorting algorithm. Using C#'s built-in sorting methods will absolutely destroy your algorithm in performance in the general case. Anyway, just change `if (FH[n] > FH[i])` to `if (FHM[n].Item1 > FHM[i].Item1)` and change the type of `temp` to match your tuple type.

Comment: What problem are you having making it work for tuplese? Is it not exactly the same except in your comparisons rather than comparing the values themselves you are using a property on the tuple? ie `FH[n].First > FH[i].First`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        var S2 = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        var temp = Tuple.Create(0.00, 0, 0);

        for (int i = 0; i < FHM.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int n = 0; n < i; n++)
            {
                if (FHM[n].Item1 > FHM[i].Item1)
                {
                    temp = FHM[i];
                    FHM[i] = FHM[n];
                    FHM[n] = temp;
                }
            }
        }

        S2.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Ticks S2 ForLoop = " + S2.ElapsedTicks); // 4000 ElapsedTicks

        S2.Reset();
        S2.Start();

        FHM.Sort();

        S2.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Ticks S2 List.Sort(); = " + S2.ElapsedTicks); // 700000 ElapsedTicks
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you seem unconcerned with the sorting algorithm itself, you can iterate over the Tuples and offload the sort to a SortedList like so:

> Sort a List of numeric Tuples

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Tuple<double, int, int>> FHM = new List<Tuple<double, int, int>>();
            FHM.Add(Tuple.Create(2500.00, 1, 5));
            FHM.Add(Tuple.Create(2400.00, 2, 300));
            FHM.Add(Tuple.Create(2300.00, 4, 10));
            FHM.Add(Tuple.Create(2600.00, 1, 325));

            var sorted = new SortedList<double, Tuple<double, int, int>>();
            foreach (Tuple<double, int, int> t in FHM)
            {
                sorted.Add(t.Item1, t);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OP said they want to do it with for loops to compare performance. I don't see how offloading the sorting to a SortedList does that.

Comment: @TheFastCat Thanks. This works fine but it takes 1,800.000 ElapsedTicks. Whereas the ForLoop version below takes only 4,000.